# What are possible causes for Paypal Sandbox IPN url not to be executed?

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-ipn

I am trying to implement a paypal payment using sandbox but I can't seem to get the hang of it why it is not able to call/reach/execute my IPN url.

I have been reading around the forums an tried several solution but nothing seems to help me solve my problem.

I got this simple form code:

```
<form action=" https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" name="form2" id="form2">
    <input name="first_name" required="" size="40" type="text">
    <input name="last_name" required="" size="40" type="text">
    <input name="email" size="40" type="email">
    <input name="item_name" size="40" type="text" value="Test Item">
    <input name="amount" type="hidden" value="0.01">
    <input name="cmd" type="hidden" value="_xclick">
    <input name="business" type="hidden" value="test-seller8@test.co.uk">
    <input name="notify_url" type="hidden" value="http://myurl.com/ipn.php">
    <input name="return" type="hidden" value="http://myurl.com/result.php">
    <input name="currency_code" type="hidden" value="GBP">
    <input name="no_shipping" type="hidden" value="1">
    <input type="submit" value="Pay now!">
</form>
```

I suppose that my form is fine, I could go to the paypal payment and pay using the sandbox personal account type and it would give a link to redirect to my return page where in as i click it, it would go to the correct page.

The problem is that my IPN script is not executed. This is the code in my IPN.

```
if(strcmp($_REQUEST['payment_status'],'Completed') == 0)
{
    $fd = fopen(dirname(__FILE__).'/results/payment-result.txt', 'wb');

    //dump request to file
    fwrite($fd, "### $_REQUEST = ### \n");
    fwrite($fd, print_r($_REQUEST, true));  
}
else 
{
    echo 'No direct access';    
}
```

I have tried removing the if statement to check whether the payment status is completed or not just to check if the script is execute but no, it doesn't even create the .txt file. I also tried to check whether there is an error in my IPN code by directly accessing it but it seems to be fine and it creates the file and logs the request variables.

I also tried using the IPN simulator but whenever I send it, it just loads like forever and then gives the error:

```
IPN Delivery Failed:I/O error: Connection timed out; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out
```

which doesn't really makes sense to me.

Now I am quite confuse in which part did I miss or what is causing the problem that my IPN is being execute at all.

Comment: looking at the error you got from IPN simulator - it appears like your IPN url is not reachable from the internet. Can you double check your IPN url ? If you can post it here - I can help verifying if I can access it or not.

Comment: Hi @Praveen , is there a way I can verify it myself?

Comment: just try to load it from your browser and see if you can reach your server or not. Make sure you are not loading it from the same machine or within the same network via vpn or something.

Comment: @Praveen I can access it directly from the browser. It seems to me like it has something to do with our server that doesn't allow the script to be accessed by the IPN call. Are there things in the server that must be setup in order to let the IPN call to reach it?

Comment: I have sent the url to your email @Praveen.

Comment: sorry for the delay - still trying to figure out what's going on. We can access it from some machines but not from all. Can you check if you have any IP filters/firewall that would deny access to your IPN for any reason ?

Comment: Do you mean in the Cpanel IP blocking? I have checked it a no IP is being blocked. (I am almost getting bald figuring this issue out :/)

Comment: so after talking with our network operations and trying to figure out why we cannot connect - this is what we were told: "Per the AT&T NOC,  this domain or IP is blacklisted due to being implicated in DDOS attacks.   They want the hosting agency to contact them." Can you please contact your hosting provider and make sure they clear this up?

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure you have IPN turned on in your PayPal settings:

- Log into your PayPal account and go to Profile → Profile & Settings → Selling Preferences → Instant Payment Notification preferences: (alternatively [click here](https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/customerprofileweb?cmd=_profile-ipn-notify) to go directly to the page, making sure you're logged into your PayPal account before you click the link)
- Click Turn On IPN on the PayPal site.
- You will then be prompted for a Notification URL, which should be any URL - it will only be replaced by your `notify_url` parameter later anyway
- Save your settings

If you've already done this then you need to make sure your Notification URL is accessible via the outside world, use something like https://www.hidemyass.com/proxy to check your site is definitely available.

Check your [IPN history](https://www.paypal.com/uk/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_display-ipns-history) on your PayPal account and you'll see the exact URL the IPN was sent to and the status.